# Prove a double inclusion of an arbitrary unions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

$B_n$ is defined as follows:

$$B_n = \{ x \in \mathbb{N} \;|\; 3n+1 < x \le 3n+4 \}$$

What I need to do is:

1. "Calculate" (not sure if that's the correct term, please correct me with the right one) the arbitrary unions of $B_n$:
   $$\bigcup_{1 \le n \in \mathbb{N}}B_n$$
2. Prove the calculation using a double inclusion (showing that each set is a subset of the other).

What I currently have:

1. Considering that $1 \le n$, I "calculated" the arbitrary unions of $B_n$ to be:
   $$\bigcup_{1 \le n \in \mathbb{N}}B_n = \{ x \in \mathbb{N} \;|\; 4 < x \}$$
2. Proving the first direction:

   Let:
   $$ x \in \bigcup_{1 \le n \in \mathbb{N}}B_n $$

   Since $1 \le n \in \mathbb{N}$, then also $4 < x \in \mathbb{N}$.

   Thus:
   $$ \bigcup_{1 \le n \in \mathbb{N}}B_n \subseteq \{ x \in \mathbb{N} \;|\; 4 < x \} $$

Now, I'm not sure if my first-direction proof is correctly written - and please correct me if it's not - but what's more of an issue here is this:

How do I approach the opposite direction proof?

I'd be glad for any guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *calculate* is fine—you could also say *compute* or *evaluate*, and you're correct that the union $\bigcup_{1 \le n \in \mathbb{N}} B_n$ is equal to $\{ x \in \mathbb{N} \mid 4 < x \}$, so let's look at the proof.

Your proof of the $\subseteq$ inclusion is *correct* but it is lacking some details. The definition of an indexed union is
$$\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i = \{ x \mid x \in X_i \text{ for some } i \in I \}$$
and this is really the definition you should be working with directly in your proof.

A more complete proof of the $\subseteq$ inclusion would look something like this:

> Let $y \in \bigcup_{1 \le n \in \mathbb{N}} B_n$. Then $y \in B_n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n \ge 1$.
>
> By definition of $B_n$, we have $3n+1 < y \le 3n+4$.
>
> Since $n \ge 1$, we have $y > 4$, and so $y \in \{ x \in \mathbb{N} \mid 4 < x \}$.

(Notice that I used the variable $y$ to avoid overloading the variable $x$.)

For the $\supseteq$ direction, you need to let $y \in \{ x \in \mathbb{N} \mid 4 < x \}$ and derive $y \in \bigcup_{1 \le n \in \mathbb{N}} B_n$, using the definition of the sets and set operations involved. Thus your proof should look like this:

> Let $y \in \{ x \in \mathbb{N} \mid 4 < x \}$.
>
> [*...here you need to find (with proof) a value of $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n \ge 1$ such that $y \in B_n$...*]
>
> Hence $y \in \bigcup_{1 \le n \in \mathbb{N}} B_n$.

The value of $n$ that you find will be given in terms of $y$.

Comment: That's a great answer. Can you kindly take a look at my comment to @Berci? it's relevant here also, and it would be great if you can refer to it as well.

Comment: For the $\supseteq$ direction, given $y \in \{ x \in \mathbb{N} \mid 4 < x \}$, in order to prove that $y \in \bigcup_{1 \le n \in \mathbb{N}} B_n$, you need to find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $y \in B_n$. That is, given $y > 4$, you have to find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $3n+1 < y \le 3n+4$. Such a value of $n$ will (typically) depend on the value of $y$. So what you have to do is (i) define $n = [\text{something to do with } y]$, and then (ii) verify that $y \in B_n$ for this value of $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'calculate' is ok, but you could also use e.g. 'find'.

The inclusion is correct, maybe you could insert a middle step: if $x$ is in the union of $B_n$'s, it means $x\in B_n$ for some $n\ge1$, thus $4\le 3n+1<x$.

For the other direction, given an $x\in\Bbb N$ greater than $4$, how can you associate the $n$ to it, such that $x\in B_n$? (Try small examples.)

Comment: *"associate the $n$ to it"* is a great phrasing, and makes me understand better what's required. However, I don't fully grasp why is it neccessary to do this "association", i.e., why isn't it trivial. After all, I've found that $x > 4$ only because I've substituted $3n+1$ with $n = 1$. So, isn't that enough to say that we have an "association of $x$ to $n$"?

Comment: It's for the other direction: $n$ will be the integer part of $\frac{x-2}3$.

Comment: I lost you here...Would be great if you can elaborate

Answer (score 1):

By evaluating the frist $B_n$'s,we get: $B_1=\{5,6,7\}$, $B_2=\{8,9,10\}$, $B_3=\{11,12,13\}$, so we see a pattern here. Each set has three consecutive numbers and, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, the last element of $B_n$ is $3n+4$ and the first element of $B_{n+1}$ is $3(n+1)+2=3n+5$, so the first element of $B_{n+1}$ is consecutive to the last element of $B_n$. Therefore, their union covers all natural numbers $n\geq5$.

Comment: Did you mean "...all natural numbers (where) $x \geq 5$"?